# Extract date part of a dataframe column and convert it to the last business day of its month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df` with `Date`  elements being a `string`  followed by `YYYY.MM` :

```
df =
             Date    Value
0  name   2019.06      1.0
1  string 2018.03      1.6
2  string 2017.12      1.0
3  string 2016.09      1.7
4  name   2018.09      6.0
...
```

And I would like to convert the `Date` column to the last business day (Monday to Friday) of its month.
So I could get this output:

```
df =
             Date    Value
0      2019-06-28      1.0
1      2018-03-30      1.6
2      2017-12-29      1.0
3      2016-09-30      1.7
4      2018-09-28      6.0
...
```

I tried `re.search`  to start by searching for the date parts of each element of the column, but I can't figure out the solution for this.

Comment: Just to be clear, the last business day of any month is a weekday (Monday through Friday) with the highest date value possible for that month. So you need to know two things, what is the last day of the month, and is it a business day? If not then move back a date at a time until you find a weekday at that date.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly that by business day = weekday (Monday through Friday)

Comment: This works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441323/finding-last-business-day-of-a-month-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split and add monthend:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.split().str[-1])
print(df.assign(Date=d + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)))
```

---

```
        Date  Value
0 2019-06-28    1.0
1 2018-03-30    1.6
2 2017-12-29    1.0
3 2016-09-30    1.7
4 2018-09-28    6.0
```

Comment: Not sure why the `split()` is necessary, but the `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd` is great.

Comment: @r.ook the data looks like `name   2019.06 `

Comment: Aaaaah, I thought that was just bad formatting on the question itself.  Bad assumption on my part!

Comment: You'll need an import for this to work. from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd

Comment: @Displayname you can also import it as i did. works for me (pandas 0.25.3)

Comment: @anky this works thank you. What if I have another dataframe but the date has no string and is only `%YYYY.MM`. How can I split this? Because I'm getting errors,  python is considering it a float number and does not  split it in the `"." `

Comment: Then ignore the split and just convert to datetime.. :)

Comment: For example, if I do that to an element like `2019.06` it is converting it to `1970-01-01`

Comment: I can't test this now as it's bedtime but are you passing any format? If yes try letting pandas infer it

Comment: I tried passing format like format = ''%Y.%m` and is writing `1970-01-01 00:00:00.2019`.
And it is the same if I don't put any format