# how to check if an input date is a business end of month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a code asks the user to input a date:

```
date_entry = input('Inserisci la data di fine mese del lancio del MAI in formato DD-MM-YYYY: ')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
date1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(datetime.date(day, month, year)))
```

then I have to check if that date is a business end of month, if yes the code continues if not it exists.
I tried this:

```
if date1 == BMonthEnd():
    pass
else:
    print("Ricontrolla: " + str(date1) + " non è un fine mese")
    exit(0)
```

here I get the error as if I input 29-05-2020 the code exit even if this date is a business end of month (its a friday). Thanks. Luigi

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441323/finding-last-business-day-of-a-month-in-python

Comment: yes that is a cleaner way I admit. Anyway that was already working, any idea on how to solve the problem?thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the `rollforward`method to check if you get the same date returned as `date1`:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = pd.to_datetime('28-05-2020', dayfirst=True)

bm_end = pd.tseries.offsets.BMonthEnd()

if date1 == bm_end.rollforward(date1):
    pass
else:
    print("Ricontrolla: " + str(date1) + " non è un fine mese")
    
# prints
# Ricontrolla: 2020-05-28 00:00:00 non è un fine mese
```

Comment: Thanks for this opportunity, buddy! Combination of rollforward / rollback makes it a big easier to manipulate with dates!