# Get last business day of the month in PySpark without UDF

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I would like to get the last business day (LBD) of the month, and use LBD to filter records in a dataframe, I did come up with python code. But to achieve this functionality I need to use UDF. Is there any way to get the last business day of the month without using PySpark UDF?

```
import calendar

def last_business_day_in_month(calendarYearMonth):
  year = int(calendarYearMonth[0:4])
  month = int(calendarYearMonth[4:])
  return str(year) + str(month) + str(max(calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)[-1:][0][:5]))
  
last_business_day_in_month(calendarYearMonth)
```

`calendarYearMonth` is in format YYYYMM

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62392077/6187792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it using `last_day` and its `dayofweek`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(202010,), (202201,)]).toDF(['yrmth']). \
    withColumn('lastday_mth', func.last_day(func.to_date(func.col('yrmth').cast('string'), 'yyyyMM'))). \
    withColumn('dayofwk', func.dayofweek('lastday_mth')). \
    withColumn('lastbizday_mth',
               func.when(func.col('dayofwk') == 7, func.date_add('lastday_mth', -1)).
               when(func.col('dayofwk') == 1, func.date_add('lastday_mth', -2)).
               otherwise(func.col('lastday_mth'))
               ). \
    show()

# +------+-----------+-------+--------------+
# | yrmth|lastday_mth|dayofwk|lastbizday_mth|
# +------+-----------+-------+--------------+
# |202010| 2020-10-31|      7|    2020-10-30|
# |202201| 2022-01-31|      2|    2022-01-31|
# +------+-----------+-------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a small [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sequence) of last dates of the month, [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html#pyspark.sql.functions.filter) out weekends and use [`array_max`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_max.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_max) to return the max date.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('202010',), ('202201',)], ['yrmth'])

last_day = F.last_day(F.to_date('yrmth', 'yyyyMM'))
last_days = F.sequence(F.date_sub(last_day, 3), last_day)
df = df.withColumn(
    'last_business_day_in_month',
    F.array_max(F.filter(last_days, lambda x: ~F.dayofweek(x).isin([1, 7])))
)

df.show()
# +------+--------------------------+
# | yrmth|last_business_day_in_month|
# +------+--------------------------+
# |202010|                2020-10-30|
# |202201|                2022-01-31|
# +------+--------------------------+
```

For lower Spark versions:

```py
last_day = "last_day(to_date(yrmth, 'yyyyMM'))"
df = df.withColumn(
    'last_business_day_in_month',
    F.expr(f"array_max(filter(sequence(date_sub({last_day}, 3), {last_day}), x -> weekday(x) < 5))")
)
```