# How do I convert yyyy-mm-dd (2018-08-09) to Aug09 in Python?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm plotting a graph with anaconda and it's taking a start_dt = x1[0] and end_dt = x1[29]. There are 30 values on the x axis. Right now, the date getting picked is already in Aug09 form. But I want to switch to another file where the dates are in yyyy-mm-dd form. How do I change the format of the date when it's getting passed to the state_dt and end_dt?

```
plt.suptitle(heading + start_dt + '-' + end_dt, size=26, fontweight='bold', va='top')
```

Comment: Someone took the time to make a [whole website dedicated to this very thing](http://strftime.org).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting string 'yyyy-mm-dd' into datetime python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779155/converting-string-yyyy-mm-dd-into-datetime-python)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Among our expectations here are that you make a reasonable effort to research the question before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_str = '2018-08-09'
d = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
print(d.strftime('%b%d')
```

See Also [the python datetime reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)